# Is there a special philosophy behind the zen of python being a cipher?

Tags: python, zen-of-python

Before checking `this.py` I was expecting the [Zen of python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python) guidelines and a print statement. I found the following instead which consists of a cipher that is translated at runtime when you run `import this`. Is there a reason behind the string being a cipher rather than the actual text?

```
s = """Gur Mra bs Clguba, ol Gvz Crgref

Ornhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.
Rkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.
Fvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.
Pbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.
Syng vf orggre guna arfgrq.
Fcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.
Ernqnovyvgl pbhagf.
Fcrpvny pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.
Nygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl orngf chevgl.
Reebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.
Hayrff rkcyvpvgyl fvyraprq.
Va gur snpr bs nzovthvgl, ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb thrff.
Gurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb qb vg.
Nygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er Qhgpu.
Abj vf orggre guna arire.
Nygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna *evtug* abj.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, vg'f n onq vqrn.
Vs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, vg znl or n tbbq vqrn.
Anzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs gubfr!"""

d = {}
for c in (65, 97):
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i+c)] = chr((i+13) % 26 + c)

print("".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s]))
```

Comment: The entire thing is tongue-in-cheek...

Comment: Yeah, it's funny

Answer (score 2):

You may find the explanation in  Barry Warsaw 2010 blog. [*Link*](https://www.wefearchange.org/2010/06/import-this-and-zen-of-python.html)

> ....Tim or Guido suggested further that we rot13 the contents of the module just for a little extra obfuscation, and we told no one outside our little group....

> ...That was all back in the day when the Python community had a sense of humor...

Comment: So, it's funny because it's undocumented? Please clarify for people like me who have no sense of humour.

Comment: Irony. The implementation of `this.py` violates virtually every tenet it espouses.